# scraping AJAX content on webpage with requests python

Tags: python, html, ajax, python-requests

I'm trying to scraping an AJAX loaded part on a webpage without executing the javascript. By using Chrome dev tool, I found that the AJAX container is pulling the content from a URL through a POST request, so I want to duplicate the request with python `requests` package. But strangely, by using the `Headers` information given from Chrome, I always get 400 error, and the same happens with the curl command copied from Chrome. So I'm wondering whether someone could kindly share some insights.

The website I'm interested in is [here](https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43). Using Chrome: ctrl-shift-I, network, XHR, and the part I want is 'content'. The script I'm using is:

```
headers = {"authority": "cafe.bithumb.com",
    "path": "/boards/43/contents",
    "method": "POST",
    "origin":"https://cafe.bithumb.com",
    "accept-language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36",
    "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "referer":"https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43",
    "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",
    "scheme": "https",
    "content-length":"1107"}
s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r = s.post('https://cafe.bithumb.com/boards/43/contents')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compare two post data, then you will find they have almost same except the a few parameter(`draw=page...start=xx`). That means you can scrape Ajax data by modifying `draw` and `start`.

Edit: Data was transformed to dictionary so we do not need `urlencode`, also we don't need cookie(i tested).

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Origin": "https://cafe.bithumb.com",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Referer": "https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
    }

string = """columns[0][data]=0&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=1&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=false&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=2&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=false&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=3&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[3][orderable]=false&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=4&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[4][orderable]=false&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&start=30&length=30&search[value]=&search[regex]=false"""


article_root = "https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/board-contents/{}"

for page in range(1,4):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)

        data = {"draw":page}
        data.update( { ele[:ele.find("=")]:ele[ele.find("=")+1:] for ele in string.split("&") } )
        data["start"] = 30 * (page - 1)

        r = s.post('https://cafe.bithumb.com/boards/43/contents', data = data, verify = False) # set verify = False while you are using fiddler

        json_data = json.loads(r.text).get("data") # transform string to dict then we can extract data easier
        for each in json_data:
            url = article_root.format(each[0])
            print(url)
```

Comment: thanks @kcorlidy, your codes works like a charm. I'm new to this, could you please elaborate about: 1.how to compare the two post data? The codes in my question was trying to replicate what I got from chrome dev tool, but I was not able to intercept the original request. 2. where did you get `data` please? 3. your codes fetches the content of the 2nd page, I've tried `page =0` but it does not work, how should I change the code? 4. It seems to take 3-4 sec to get the response compared to ~0.5 within chrome, is it normal? Sorry for the barrage of questions and thanks very much!

Comment: @Lampard 1 and 2.use fiddler  3.there is no page zero, page > 0. 4. It is normal, why you take 3-4 sec because you are setting up an new connection. And i will edit my answer to show you what to do

Comment: @Lampard i'm sorry because i haven't access page 2 at first. I found the response is dependent on `draw` and `start`. i have edited my answer and compared with browser's response(same)